# Extremal of Compact Banach Space Embedding

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, banach-spaces

Let $(X, \|\cdot \|_X)$ and $(Y,\|\cdot \|_Y)$ be (nontrivial real) Banach spaces such that $X \subseteq Y$ .

We say $X$ is compactly embedded into $Y$ if the following two conditions hold :

1. There exists a constant $C>0$ such that $\| x\|_Y \leq C\|x \|_X$ for every $x \in X$ .
2. If a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \geq 1} \subseteq X$ is bounded with respect to the norm $\|\cdot \|_X$, then its closure in $Y$ is a compact subset of $Y$.

The best constant $C$ is given by:

\begin{equation*}
C = \inf_{x \in X, x \neq 0} \frac{\| x\|_Y}{\| x\|_X}
\end{equation*}

Suppose $X$ is compactly embedded into $Y$. Does it follow that the above best constant is attained? That is, does there exist a nonzero element $x \in X$ such that $C= \frac{\| x\|_Y}{\| x\|_X}$? If not, under what additional assumption will such an extremal element exist?

My attempt:

For each positive integer $n$, there exists a nonzero element $x_n \in X$ such that:

\begin{equation*}
C \leq \frac{\| x_n\|_Y}{\| x_n\|_X} < C + \frac{1}{n}
\end{equation*}

Put $y_n = \frac{x_n}{\| x_n\|_X}$. Then $y_n \in X$, $\| y_n\|_X=1$, and:

\begin{equation*}
C \leq \frac{\| y_n\|_Y}{\| y_n\|_X}=\| y_n\|_Y < C + \frac{1}{n}
\end{equation*}

By property $2$, there is a $y \in Y$ and a subsequence $\{n_k\}_{k\geq 1}$ such that $y_{n_k} \to y$ as $k \to \infty$ with respect to the $\| \cdot \|_Y$ norm. By continuity of norm and squeeze theorem, we have $\| y \|_Y = C>0$ so that $y \neq 0$ .

Now all I need to prove is that $y \in X$. But I am stuck on this step. Clearly $\{y_{n_k}\}_{k \geq 0}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\| \cdot \|_Y$ but I have no idea about how to make it Cauchy in $X$ . On the other hand, I am unable to come up with counterexamples .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's record a Lemma.

**Lemma**.
Given $X,Y$ Banach spaces with $X$ *reflxive*, and $T:X\to Y$ a compact operator. Suppose the sequence $x_n\in X$ weakly converges to $x_\infty$, then $Tx_n$ strongly converges to $Tx_\infty$.

*Proof*: By the uniform boundedness principle, $x_n$ is norm bounded (reflexivity means weak and weak* are the same). Therefore $Tx_n$ is a bounded sequence in $Y$ and has a converging subsequence $Tx_{n_k}$ that converges to $y_\infty\in Y$.

Now, choose $\varphi\in Y^*$. The adjoint operator $T^*: Y^*\to X^*$ is continuous, and we have
$$ \varphi(Tx_n) = T^*\varphi(x_n) \to T^*\varphi(x_\infty) = \varphi(Tx_\infty) $$
by weak convergence of $x_n$. This shows that $Tx_\infty$ is a weak limit of $Tx_n$, and hence also a weak limit of $Tx_{n_k}$. But since strong limits are weak limits, we have that by the uniqueness of weak limits that $Tx_\infty = y_\infty$.

So far we have only proven convergence along a subsequence. To prove that the convergence holds for the original sequence, note that we can apply the same argument to every subsequence of the original sequence $x_n$. This shows that "every subsequence of $Tx_n$ has a further subsequence that converges strongly to $Tx_\infty$", which implies (standard exercise) that $Tx_n \to Tx_\infty$. Q.E.D.

---

Returning to your question, when $X$ is reflexive, given your maximizing sequence $x_n$ with constant $\|x_n\|_X = 1$ and
$$ \frac{\|x_n\|_Y}{\|x_n\|_X} \nearrow C = \sup \frac{\|x\|_Y}{\|x\|_X} $$
By Banach-Alaoglu we can WLOg assume this sequence weakly converges to $x_\infty$. By the Lemma we know that $\|x_\infty\|_Y = C$. It suffices to show that $\|x_\infty\|_X = 1$.

Using the dual characterization we have that
$$ \|x_\infty\|_X = \sup_{z\in X^*, \|z\|_{X^*} = 1} x_\infty(z) $$
By weak (weak*) convergence, we have
$$ x_\infty(z) = \lim x_n(z) \leq \|x_n\|_X \|z\|_{X^*} = 1 $$
Hence we have $\|x_\infty\|_X \leq 1$. It suffices to show that it is impossible for $\|x_\infty\|_X < 1$.

This final step holds because, were it the case that $\|x_\infty\|_X < 1$, then by our argument we've shown that $\|x_\infty\|_Y / \|x_\infty\|_X > C$, contradicting the fact that $C$ is the optimum constant (the supremum).

---

*Remark*: much of this proof can be adapted to pick up where you left off in your attempt, after you fixed the mistake between inf and sup. However, notice that **nowhere did I assert that $x_n$ converges strongly to $x_\infty$**. All I did is prove that $x_\infty$ has norm 1.

*Remark 2*: this proof relies on multiple spots that $X$ is reflexive. Some of them are possibly gratuitous. (I think the Lemma above doesn't really require reflexivity.) However, Banach-Alaoglu only gives you weak*, and to apply the Lemma I do need to pass to weak convergence, so off hand I don't know whether the argument can be extended to when $X$ is not reflexive.

Comment: The Lemma is true with weak-star convergence if $T$ is itself an adjoint operator (which requires  $X,Y$ to be dual spaces).

Comment: Isn't the Lemma always true? Just use the fact that norm continuous operators are weak-weak continuous. Maybe I am missing something...

Comment: @DavidMitra: yes, in fact the proof pretty much say the same. I know it works for sure with reflexivity, and know that the Main part likely requires reflexivity [see also daw's counterexample], so didn't feel particularly inclined to double check whether the Lemma needs reflexivity. (See also Remark 2 in my answer.) // In short, let me be lazy about MSE answers.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is not true without reflexivity.
Or at least not true if the spaces have no pre-dual.

Take
$$
Y = L^1(0,1)
$$
and
$$
X = \{ u \in W^{1,1}(0,1): \ u(0)=0\}.
$$
Note that functions in $X$ satisfy the estimate
$$
|u(t)| \le \|u'\|_{L^1} \quad\forall t\in (0,1).
$$
Then one can check that $\|u\|_X:= \|u'\|_{L^1(0,1)}$ is a norm on $X$,
and
$$
\|u\|_Y=\|u\|_{L^1} \le \|u'\|_{L^1}=\|u\|_X \quad \forall u\in X.
$$
The constant $C=1$ is the best possible: Define $u_n=\min(nx,1)\in X$. Then $\|u_n\|_X=1$ and $\|u_n\|_Y=1-\frac1{2n}$.

But there is no $u\in X\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\|u\|_X=\|u\|_Y$:
Assume $u\in X$ such that $1 = \|u\|_{L^1}=\|u'\|_{L^1}$.
Then $|u(t)|\le 1$, and $\|u\|_{L^1}=1$ only if $u$ is identical one, which violates $u(0)=0$.

Comment: That's a nice and easy counterexample. I will keep that in mind in the future.